# Rspec method 'be_following' from Michael Hartl's RoR tutorial chapter 11 Following USers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, rspec, model

I'm wondering where this method 'be_following' from chapter 11 came from?  Here's the snippet from the user_spec:

```
describe "following" do
  it { should be_following(other_user) }
  its(:followed_users) { should include(other_user) }

  describe "followed user" do
    subject { other_user }
    its(:followers) { should include(@user) }
  end
end
```

I don't understand how this method is created.  As far as I know it's not a default rspec or capybara method.  I'm not even sure whether or not in rspec you can use the rails generated methods from when you define model relationships such as has_many and belongs_to.  Is that so?  And why in this case is there the method be_following when that is not even defined in the models. Here's the User model:

```
has_many :years
has_many :relationships, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :follower_id
has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               class_name:  "Relationship",
                               dependent:   :destroy
has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

def following?(followed)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(followed)
end

def follow!(followed)
    relationships.create!(:followed_id => followed.id)
end

def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy!
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSpec has build-in dynamic matchers for methods with '?' at the end.

Ex.: if object responds to following? then you'll be able to write test like

```
it {object.should be_following}
```

The same works if you need to pass parameter to the method.

Documentation: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/predicate-matchers

Some more examples:

```
class A
  def has_anything?; true end
  def has_smth?(a); !a.nil?  end
  def nice?; true end
  def as_nice_as?(x); x == :unicorn end
end

describe A do
  it {should have_anything}
  it {should have_smth(42)}
  it {should be_nice}
  it {should be_as_nice_as(:unicorn)}
  it {should_not be_as_nice_as(:crocodile)}
end
```

So it's be_, be_a_, be_an_ for any method ending with '?' and have_ for has_...? methods.
Params are passed like:

```
should be_like(:ruby)
```

Custom matchers are used for more complecated checks with ability to customize success and failure messages.

Comment: "The same works if you need to pass parameter to the method." Can you give an example of this?

Comment: Also, I'm wondering if all that is required for this predicate method is writing a method with a "?" at the end.  This link http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.1.11/classes/Spec/Matchers.html says you need a class for custom matchers?

Comment: I've added some examples to the answer